# Switching Database based on condition in JAVA

Tags: java, database

I want to build a functionality which involves switching database connection in JAVA.

Basically, I have a rest API, which would accept path params like `/datasource/{dbName}/quantity/{quantity}`

I want to perform certain operation on a table called `ITEMS`.

The `ITEMS` table is present in 3 different DBs on 3 different hosts. I would want to run the update query on the host which would be identified by the **dbName** as passed in the request. I want to keep the connection string and other details within the API and the consumer would just pass the environment name to update the `ITEMS` table in that specific environment.

So basically, if the user passes `/datasource/PAFAT/quantity/1` then the `ITEMS` table on the `PAFAT` host should get updated.

Any leads on how I can make this switching of datasources dynamically.
I am okay to use Spring data JPA, JDBC template.

Comment: If you have 3 dbs, why not keep 3 connections?

Comment: How will you have multiple db connections?

Comment: @derek How do you set up one connection?

Comment: Have a look at multy tenancy in spring, I think this an example of what you want: https://medium.com/@vivekmadurai/multi-tenancy-in-rest-api-a570d728620c